# Animating an image not playing in game scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to make an animation of a countdown.

I first made a Gameobject, created a canvas for it, and inside that canvas I created a UI Image, attached an image to it, and finally created an animation with that image.

Everything is working fine except the animation is not showing in game scene but only in normal scene, but when I go to that UI Image component and start the game I can see the image changing which means that its not the animation but something else.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities.  Depending on if the image is showing up at all, you can check if your UI image is anchored correctly (four triangle marks) or pivot position is where you want it (circle mark).  Depending on how this is done, if you Game window resizes in play-mode with the display set to Free Aspect, your image may move off the visible screen or, in some cases, get crushed which usually shows up as a red X in the editor.  I can see this happening if your Game window is set to Maximize on Play.